# ABC Virtual OStream Insertion Operator

Tags: c++, virtual

Consider the following snippet:

```
struct ObjectInterface
{
    virtual ~ObjectInterface() {}
    virtual void Print(std::ostream& target) const = 0;
};

struct Foo : ObjectInterface
{
    virtual void Print(std::ostream& target) const
    {
        target << "Foo";
    }
};

struct Bar : ObjectInterface
{
    virtual void Print(std::ostream& target) const
    {
        target << "Bar";
    }
};
```

Is there any way to change `Print` in `ObjectInterface` to the standard "`std::ostream& operator<<`"-type of output? I can't make it work.

EDIT: I'm basically trying to figure out if I can make `friend` work with `virtual`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a free function:

```
ostream & operator << ( ostream & os, const ObjectInterface & oi ) {
    oi.Print( os );
    return os;
}
```

Comment: God, that's terribly simple. I can't believe I didn't think of that... Thanks.

Comment: Don't feel too bad. The first guy at Bell Labs (I guess) that thought of it was probably pretty pleased with himself - the rest of us just use it.